# Write data into flash using simulator TOSSIM

Tags: assembly, tinyos

```
#define BITINIT \
  uint8_t clrClkAndData = PORTD & ~0x28

#define BIT(n) \
    PORTD = clrClkAndData; \
    asm __volatile__ \
        (  "sbrc %2," #n "\n" \
     "\tsbi 18,3\n" \
     "\tsbi 18,5\n" \
     "\tsbic 16,2\n" \
     "\tori %0,1<<" #n "\n" \
     : "=d" (spiIn) : "0" (spiIn), "r" (spiOut))
```

I installed ubuntu and using TOSSIM. Everything compiles properly and is running. But when the file HPLAt45dbIOP.nc for micaz is executed on TOSSIM, I get errors like

```
 /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/chips/at45db/HplAt45dbIOP.nc:
```

Assembler messages:

```
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/chips/at45db/HplAt45dbIOP.nc:150: Error: no such instruction: `sbrc %cl,7'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/chips/at45db/HplAt45dbIOP.nc:151: Error: no such instruction: `sbi 18,3'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/chips/at45db/HplAt45dbIOP.nc:152: Error: no such instruction: `sbi 18,5'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/chips/at45db/HplAt45dbIOP.nc:153: Error: no such instruction: `sbic 16,2'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/chips/at45db/HplAt45dbIOP.nc:154: Error: no such instruction: `ori %dl,1<<7'
```

I have an Intel machine. Why does TOSSIM unable to run assembly language instructions?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `sbrc`, `sbi`, and so on are AVR Assembler instructions, so an Intel machine cannot execute them.

Nevertheless, TOSSIM does not and cannot run the same platform-dependent components as real nodes. Such components use microcontroller's registers for controlling IO pins, handle hardware interrupts, communicate with external peripherals over buses such as SPI, etc. Apart from wireless sensor networks: imagine you have an application that takes photo from a camera plugged to a PC and then prints it. How would you simulate execution of such application without physical possesion of a camera and a printer?

What TOSSIM actually does, is that *it works by replacing components with simulation implementations* (see [documentation](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/TOSSIM)). Compared to the PC application I mentioned before, TOSSIM works by substituting certain hardware components, such as a printer and a camera, by software modules simulating their behavior, so-called **mocks**. The application then communicates with such software modules instead of real hardware, what allows for testing higher layers of the application logic without having physical hardware.

This approach, however, requires implementing software mocks, what sometimes is not necessarily easy. The TinyOS *micaz* platform, which, as far as I know, is the only one supporting TOSSIM, comes with some mock modules. You can find them in directories named *sim*. For instance, *tos/platforms/micaz/chips/cc2420/sim/* contains mocks for the CC2420 radio chip and *tos/chips/atm128/timer/sim/* includes mocks for hardware timers available on the ATM128 microcontroller.

In TinyOS, when compiling with a command `make micaz sim`, mock components are automatically used instead of real implementations by preceding all include paths with include paths ending with `/sim` (the TinyOS build system chooses always a first matching component).

Unfortunately, it seems there is no mock for the flash memory driver, so it is not possible to use flash in simulations. You need to have a MICAz mote to test your application. TOSSIM is mainly used for simulations concerning radio, because such experiments cannot always be easily performed in a real environment and their results may be indeterministic, what hinders reproducing issues and debugging applications.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway in which the assembly code given be changed

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: I want the data collected by the sensor to be written to flash memory. For this I have used BlockStorageC component, I also had initially faced a problem for creation of StorageVolumes.h file which I resolved using tos-storage-at45db command manually.  I want to know that when TOSSIM simulates the sensor nodes, does it also allow some form of storage in the simulated sensor node so that if any such experiments like sending and storing data on flash memory can be made possible through TOSSIM. The error is coming in file HPLat45dbIOP.nc

Comment: Or is it that the avr assembler path is not being taken or cross compilation is not happening.

Comment: Read my previous answer carefully. It is not possible to run experiments that use flash memory in TOSSIM, unless you implement mocks for flash memory modules (which is probably not what you want to do). I recommend testing your application on physical MICAz motes. By the way, cross compilation means that a compiler runs on a different architecture than it creates an executable for. You do not want to have cross compilation when you use TOSSIM, because your simulation will take place on the same machine the application is compiled.

Comment: I was trying to distribute data collected on one sensor to other sensors. Then this will not be possible on TOSSIM. What can be done ? Are there any other simulators which will support this? Any clues

Comment: From the most to the least recommended (by me) option:
1. Test your application on real, physical sensor nodes.
2. Avoid using flash memory in simulations, use RAM instead.
3. Implement mocks for the flash memory storage abstractions you use.

Comment: 1. Currently I do not have hardware for this 2. Please let me know how to use RAM instead of flash on TOSSIM 3.I have no idea how to implement mocks for flash 4. Do you have any idea does MATLAB have any tool box for sensor networks 5. Please guide me if you have any alternative to work on this problem

Comment: 2. Instead of writing to flash, save data in an array defined in your application's state.
3. So probably that's not what you want to do.
4. I don't know.
5. I think I already wrote everything and you need to find and browse some nesC and TinyOS tutorials.